# CSV file gives error on reading with open() in python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, readfile, ioexception, python-unicode

```
import unicodecsv
engagement_file=r'G:\college\udacity\intro to data analitics\datasets\daily_engagement.csv'
enrollment_file=r'G:\college\udacity\intro to data analitics\datasets\enrollments.csv'
project_submissions_file=r'G:\college\udacity\intro to data analitics\datasets\project_submissions.csv'
def csv_to_list(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file,'rb') as f:
        reader=unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
    return list(reader)

daily_engagement=csv_to_list(engagement_file)
enrollment=csv_to_list(enrollment_file)
project_submissions=csv_to_list(project_submissions_file)
```

on executing this piece of code I get following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\college\udacity\intro to data analitics\data_analytis_csv_to_list.py", line 10, in <module>
    daily_engagement=csv_to_list(engagement_file)
  File "G:\college\udacity\intro to data analitics\data_analytis_csv_to_list.py", line 8, in csv_to_list
    return list(reader)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py2.py", line 217, in next
    row = csv.DictReader.next(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\csv.py", line 108, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py2.py", line 117, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I dont know how to solve it ,I m new to python
thanks in advance

Comment: voting to close this as it is a simple typographical error - you've just missed one level of indentation for your `return`

Comment: @asongtoruin Yes, technically you _could_ say that. But I don't think closing the question as a typo would be valid. It came from a fundamentally misunderstanding of how the context manager works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `with open() as f:` in python the file `f` is only open *inside* the `with` clause. That is the point of using it; it provides automatic file closing and cleaning in a easy and readable way.

If you want to work on the file either open it without the `with` clause (that is plain opening a file) **or** do the operations on that file *inside* the clause, calling it directly as `f`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your return under your `with` statement. Once control flow has gone out of the `with` statement, Python automatically closes the file for you. That means any file I/O you have to do needs to be done under the context manager:

```
def csv_to_list(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file,'rb') as f:
        reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader) # return the file under the context manager
```